# Amazon S3 PHP SDK: uploaded images have wrong mime types

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I tried the following two functions, none of them works, they could upload the file to S3 but if you visit the uploaded file from a browser you could see it's being treated as application/octet-stream, that's not right...

```
$s3->upload('mybucket', // bucket
    $filename, // key
    $imagebinarydata, // body
    'public-read', // acl
    array('contentType' => 'image/jpeg')); // options
```

And

```
$s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'        => 'mybucket',
    'Key'           => $filename,
    'ACL'           => 'public-read',
    'contentType'   => 'image/jpeg',
    'Body'          => $imagebinarydata));
```

I'm using the latest AWS.PHAR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use uppercase `ContentType` with `putObject` as described in [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject):

```
'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
```